# multiprocessing missing when running image uploading sample code under Windows

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I try to follow exactly the image uploading code published in http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages.html

I use the following `app.yaml` file

```
application: jstock-webapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /*
  script: upload.py
- url: /sign
  script: upload.py
- url: /img
  script: upload.py
```

I get the following error.

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named _multiprocessing
      args = ('No module named _multiprocessing',)
      message = 'No module named _multiprocessing'
```

[image]

I check my Python runtime environment by launching `c:\Python26\python.exe`

I get the following output

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import multiprocessing
>>>
```

Is there anything I had missed?

Comment: @NickJohnson The code is in the google's link above. Just after "We now have completed our modified Guestbook application:"

Comment: You must have modified it - that app.yaml doesn't match what's in the demo, and indeed has an error in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you try to import `_multiprocessing`, not `multiprocessing`.

See [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1504) for a variety of workarounds, foremost of which is to use Python 2.5 instead of 2.6. Better yet, install Python 2.7 and [update your app](http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe) to target it.